# wait between request in rtk query

Tags: react-native, redux, rtk-query

I wanna call this query

```
    searchMulti: builder.query<any, ISearchMotion>({
  query: ({query, motionType}: ISearchMotion) =>
    `/search/${motionType}?query=${query}`,
  transformErrorResponse: e => console.log({e}),
  transformResponse: (response: any) => response,
}),
```

after the user stops typing in text input, not every character entered
how should I do that?

Comment: debounce the query - you can try something like https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

Answer (score 0):

Move the query to a different sub component, as the query triggers as soon as the component loads. You can control the component that has this query to show after the user stops typing in text input by a state variable.
Or change the query to a mutation and you can call it on click after the input is complete.

Comment: I can refer to some examples if needed.

Comment: I mean, has rtk query built-in function for this job? @Marcia-Moss

Comment: Not that am aware of, am sure RTK documentation will have more info on it.  The debounce suggested above would be a good solution as well if you want a timed wait. Either way you have to set it up in such a way as when you want the query to trigger. RTK will not know unless you tell it when you want the query to run and that can be controlled with state variable debounce way or loading the component with query after something is completed.